# Reference to objects id in QML

Tags: python, qt, qml

I'm trying to define a generic button in QML for use in other components. It should call a `onCLick` method on a object and pass its id to the function. Everything works except for the id part.

The button is defined with the following code:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 20
    color: "#d1d7f5"
    radius: 10
    property string btnText

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: parent.color = "#645fa9"
        onReleased: parent.color = "#d1d7f5"
        onClicked: {
            context.onClicked(this.id) /// This is the line of problem
        }
    }
    border.color: "#645fa9"
    border.width: 2

    Text {
        id: textBtn
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        color: "#2e3b7f"
        text: parent.btnText
        font.bold: true
        font.family: "Verdana"
        font.pixelSize: 30
    }

}
```

The button can the be used in another QML file as this:

```
Button {
    id: button1
    x: 141
    y: 30
    btnText: "A Button"

}
```

The Python I use to receive the signal is here:

```
class Context(QObject):

    @Slot(object)
    def onClicked(self, btn):
        print btn
```

When the button is clicked it prints `None`. If `this.id` is replaced with a string it prints the string. 
I also tried to give the `Rectangle` an `id` property, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to get its id field.
You might add an extra property or use your btnText for the purpose of distinguishing buttons.